# Jump to last position in current file

Tags: vim

I enjoy <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> quite a bit, but it tends to jump me to other files. The way I work is I have many files open simultaneously across windows and also across different instances of Vim so I can see them at the same time, and switch between them.

So I'd rather have it just jump within a single file. Ideally I can have two separate commands, one that does the normal `<C-O>` that goes across files (and is like a chronological path of where I have been) and another that does this only in the currently opened file.

Is there perhaps a way to script this? Hopefully there's a plugin out there. I think it would just need to scan through the jumplist filtering out all files that are not this file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can jump though the changelist (`:help changelist`) with `g;` (back) and `g,` (forth).

It is local so there's no way you'd jump to another buffer but it's a "change"list so only changes are remembered, not motions.

Comment: Looks like the changlist is a separate but similar-enough-to-be-helpful feature separate from jumps but which just happens to be tracked on a per file basis. My instinctive guess is that the undo file `<filename>.un~` contains both undo tree change content and the changelist!

Comment: Changelist is superior to jumps. I don't need to hop through all my search matches for instance.

Answer (score 3):

My [EnhancedJumps plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2695) defines variants of `<C-o>` that either stay in the current buffer, or immediately jump to a cursor position in another buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use marks for what you want. If you pres <kbd>m</kbd>+"some lower case letter", eg. <kbd>m</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>. This saves your current cursor position in `a`. You can then use <kbd>'</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to jump back to that position. With lower case letters, the mark is saved pr file basis, if you use an upper case letter, then it's valid between open files.

See [marks help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%3amarks) for more info.

Comment: Indeed marks are useful but if I'm gonna make the effort to bend down to plant a flag somewhere, they'll be important places. The main purpose of my `<C-O>` use is to go back to where I don't remember I was. Turns out if my text editor can help out carrying the load of medium-term memory, I will gladly take advantage of it. As you might imagine there is an exceedingly low chance of the place I don't remember possessing a mark (and if it did, a compounded lower chance I'll remember **which** mark)